# Insert to monogdb from a form in a nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, insert

I'm getting this error message:

```
[![error message][1]][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okcb7.jpg

These are the contents of my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/emedb');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
var userSchema = new Schema({
name: { type: String, required: true,},
email: { type: String, required: true,},
password: { type: String, required: true },
location: String,
age: Number,
created_at: Date,
updated_at: Date
});

// on every save, add the date
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
// get the current date
var currentDate = new Date();

// change the updated_at field to current date
this.updated_at = currentDate;

// if created_at doesn't exist, add to that field
if (!this.created_at)
this.created_at = currentDate;

next();
});

var User = mongoose.model('emedb', userSchema);

// post to db
app.post('/newBen', function(req,res){
new user({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email, 
    password: req.body.password,
    location: req.body.location,
    age: req.body.age,
    created_at: req.currentDate,
    updated_at: req.currentDate
}).save(function(err, doc){
    if(err)res.json(err);
    else res.send('Thank you for joining');
});res.end();
});

module.exports = User;
```

Plus about another 70 lines which I thought was a bit too much to post here. There's also my form which is in a pretty standard jade file. I'll post it if needs be. It has a name and a class, the method is post and the action is /new.

This is my first try at mongodb and I feel like I'm pretty close to getting it. Or am I miles away? I tried finding tutorials and most of this code came from one, but I suspect it might be a couple of years old.

Comment: Where is your 'app' defined ? will u show me top of app.js containg app declaration?

Comment: Please see the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line  .

you have not created server instance

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
```

Comment: That's lower in the file. Under the routing.

Comment: Is it come after your mongo insert?

Comment: Yes it is. Should it be before?

Comment: yes.Thats why u getting error can read post of undefined.Please put it before mongo insert or better where included express

Comment: That seems to be getting it closer. I'm getting another error message now.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'moniker' of undefined
    at D:\node\eme\app.js:47:20

Comment: I think moniker is not part of your code in given POST

Comment: Its better if you put all your declaration and defination before u use it

Comment: Woops. I changed 'name' to 'moniker' thinking that 'name' might be a reserved word.